# Sort ArrayList of class objects by float field

Tags: java

I am storing Item objects in an ArrayList. The Item class has a float field called `field1`. I want to retrieve Item objects from `itemsList` in the decreasing order of `field1`.

```
List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemsList.add(new Item(...));
```

This is what I tried:

```
public class Item implements Comparable {

    //...

    public float compareTo(Item it)
    {
        return(similarity - it.similarity);
    }
}

List<Item> sortedItems = Collections.sort(itemsList);
```

The problem is that `compareTo` should return `int`, while I have `float`. So, which approach should I apply to sort `float` values?

Comment: Did you try to convert float to int? use `Math.round()`

Comment: See this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_float.htm

Comment: If you do that then floats that round to the same number will be treated as equal

Comment: `implements Comparable` should be `implements Comparable<Item>`.

Comment: @Pshemo: Ok, now it compiles, but I get the error in `List<Item> sortedItems = Collections.sort(itemsList);`. It says `Incompatible types: Required List, found void`.

Comment: `Collections.sort(itemsList);` doesn't return anything (its return type is `void`). It just sorts elements in passed collection. There is no need for `List<Item> sortedItems =` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature should be:

```
public int compareTo(Item it)
```

instead of returning a `float`. At the moment you are not implementing the `Comparable` interface.

The easiest implementation would be:

```
public int compareTo(Item it) {
  return Float.compare(similarity, it.similarity);
}
```

Comment: In case of `public int compareTo(Item it) {
  return Float.compare(similarity, it.similarity);
}`, I get error `Method does not overrides ...`.

Comment: Ha yes, you have removed the generic bit in Comparable. Change your class to `public class Item implements Comparable<Item>` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exact return value of `campareTo()` does not matter. It is either lower than 0, exactly 0 or greater than 0. you can for example return -1 for every difference below 0, 1 for every difference greater than 0, and finally 0 for 0.

As `Float` is already Comparable this would be easy: `similarity.compareTo(it.similarity)`

Answer (score 0):

compareTo is suppose to return only 3 possible values. 1, 0, -1. 1 means that the object is greater then what is being compared to, 0 means they are equal, and -1 means the object is smaller then what it is being compared to. So your compareTo method should be pretty simple.

```
public int compareTo(Item it)
    {
        if(this.field1 < it.getField1()) {
          return -1;
        }
        else if( this.field1 > it.getField1()) {
           return 1;
        }
       else {
       return 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot assign `@Override`, while the class implements Comparable.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: @victor `compareTo` can return any `int` it wants, not just -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes you are correct, mistake on my part. Im pretty sure the convention in java though is to use -1, 1, 0.